# Is it possible to customize google fabric's/digits login popup?

Tags: twitter-digits, fabric-digits, google-fabric

I know it's possible to embed widget of digits using [this link](https://docs.fabric.io/web/digits/embeddable.html)

This one will be shown on my page inside the div with `class=my-digits-container`

But is it possible to customize the popup which appears by using `Digits.logIn`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Todd here from Fabric. Right now it's not possible to customize the pop up in Digits for web. You can only theme using the embedded widget.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply Todd. Do you have this planned in future? If yes, when?